# The meaning of colon in flutter widgets structure

Tags: flutter, dart

I have learned Dart and when I started learning Flutter, I got confused by some parts of Flutter code.

Can someone tell me what's the meaning of the colon (:) after child, in the following code:

```
 const Center(
      child: Text(
        'Hello, world!',
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      ),
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is used on named constructor. The `textDirection` is an optional named parameter on `Text` widget.

```dart
class Foo {
  final int data;
  Foo({
    required this.data,
  });
}
```

Here `Foo` class has single integer `data` field, and using named required constructor to create instance.

```dart
final foo = Foo(data: 1);
```

Now If it was optional as `textDirection`, we aren't forced to pass it when creating a Foo instance like

```dart
class Foo {
  final int? data;
  Foo({
    this.data,
  });
}

void main(List<String> args) {
  final foo = Foo();
}
```

Now explore the `Text`, It contains one `String` position filed and others are optional positional argument.

Here we are forced to pass a String, but `data` is optional

```dart
class Foo {
  final String text;
  final int? data;
  Foo(this.text, {this.data});
}

void main(List<String> args) {
  final foo = Foo("test");
}
```

The `Text` widget has been defined like

```dart
  const Text(
    String this.data, {
    super.key,
    this.style,
    this.strutStyle,
    this.textAlign,
    this.textDirection,
    this.locale,
    .......
```

Find more about using [constructors](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#constructors) and [`Text`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, What I am looking for is the meaning of the code in Dart terms. I still can't find the way to bridge between Dart and Flutter. For example, what is the object, parameter, constructor in the code above. especially, what relationship does the colon (:) create between child and text.

Comment: Flutter is a framework that use dart language.

Comment: Check dart.dev to learn more about dart, and then visit flutter.dev

Comment: I learned Dart actually. It is the only problem I have. The logic behind that colon (:).  "child: Text" for example, is it a parameter or constructor? what relationship between child and text?

Comment: in that case `Center` widget have an optional named parameter named `child:`, you can search Center widget on dart.dev